# Increment and Change counter based on change in a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query returns result like this. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f9149/1)

```
COLOR_NAME

RED
RED
RED
GREEN
GREEN
BLUE
WHITE
WHITE
WHITE
WHITE
WHITE
WHITE
```

I need to show number with above result. So the desired result is like this.

```
COLOR_NAME SORT_NO

RED         10
RED         11
RED         12
GREEN       10
GREEN       11
BLUE        10
WHITE       10
WHITE       11
WHITE       12
WHITE       13
WHITE       14
WHITE       15
```

How could I achieve this in ms sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) function

```
select COLOR_NAME 
, 9 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLOR_NAME ORDER BY ID) AS Sort_No
from TB_COLOR
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f9149/4)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Saved my day.